# Кросплатформенный Web-GUI на C# -- в какую сторону смотреть?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, sqlite, gui, mono

Нужно сделать простенькую кросплатформенную(Windows, Linux, mac OS) апликуху с Web-GUI.
В апликухе нету ничего сложного - простое взаимодействие с базой данных SQLite. Добавление и убирание полей в таблицах.

Нужно понять в какую сторону копать. Я догадываюсь что нужна связка mono + какой-то веб-сервер и, возможно, WX.Net

Хочу узнать у тех кто уже сталкивался с подобным на практике. Какую связку оптимально использовать?

Comment: А что есть Web-GUI?

Comment: @VladD на сколько я понимаю возможный минимум -- HTML/CSS/JS. Возможно что больше(потому и спрашиваю про веб-сервер).

Comment: Не нужно пытаться писать кроссплатформенные приложения на .NET, для этого есть гораздо более подходящие и менее проприетарные аналоги.

Comment: Если веб, то можете копнуть в сторону Nancy (вариант self-hosted, где оно само себе сервер). Если же не веб, то в сторону AvaloniaUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял, что речь идет исключительно о .NET стэке? Если так, то .NET Core или Mono в качестве среды, ASP.NET 5 в качестве платформы, [Kestrel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kestrel) в качестве хоста.

Для начала -- презентация ["Простой и кросс-платформенный web-сервер на .NET"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbdPSlGJp48) с SPb.NET Community. А дальше Гугл со всякими мануалами в помощь.

Comment: a как быть если я хочу кросплатформенность по-возможности без ASP.NET 5? Ведь моно с .NET 5 фреймворком не работает. Кестрел не работает без .NET 5.

Comment: @Andrew: А это не подойдёт? http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

Comment: @VladD, а получится ли сбилдать кросплатформенный проэкт через моно? Я вот лично не работал и не уверен, ибо я не вижу поддержки .Net 5 у моно в принципе даже в теории пока что.

Comment: @Andrew: Эээ... Версии .NET 5 [вовсе нету](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history), максимальная текущая версия 4.6. А C# 5 и даже C# 6 [поддерживаются](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).

Comment: @VladD, что, взаправду нету? А это что? http://www.asp.net/vnext  И что написано в ридми к Kestrel ? =)

Comment: @Andrew ASP.NET и .NET -- это две разные вещи с разными номерами версий.

Comment: @VladD, Да, прошу прощения. И вправду ступил(

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ начиная с версии 3.2 позволяет запускать любые приложения прямо в Web браузере

[пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/212705/) как это делаеться,
 но для C# используйте соответсвующее Gtk# биндинги

Comment: а там сервер внешний нужен под такое дело? Иль предоставляется как часть GTK+?